# How to pass a Series object to time.mktime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy, utc

One of the columns in my dataframe is of dtype `datetime64` in the format -     `2011-01-01 00:00:00`

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

Now, I want to copy the column in a new df, and convert the values to UTC timestamps. I have tried the following methods:

```
from pytz import utc, timezone
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

input_dt = pd.to_datetime(df["BaseDateTime"])
input_dt

mktime(timezone('US/Eastern').localize(input_dt).utctimetuple())
#OR 
mktime(utc.localize(input_dt).utctimetuple())
```

After executing last two statements, it throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

What other method I should use to get the utc timestamps of the BaseDateTime col of the data frame?

Comment: maybe need `df["BaseDateTime"].dt.tz_localize('UTC')`, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#working-with-time-zones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good way to convert `datetime` values to epoch values is to create a `datetime.timedelta` by subtracting the epoch time from the date to be converted.  This function does that and can be applied to a `pandas.Series` or to a column of a `pandas.DataFrame`.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pytz import timezone

def convert_naive_dt_to_utc_epoch(naive_dt, tz_info):
    # assign proper timezone to datetime
    aware = tz_info.localize(naive_dt).astimezone(timezone('UTC'))

    # get a datetime that is equal to epoch in UTC
    utc_at_epoch = timezone('UTC').localize(dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1))

    # return the number of seconds since epoch
    return (aware - utc_at_epoch).total_seconds()
```

**Test Code:**

```
data = [np.datetime64(x) for x in
        "2016-10-18T13:44:59 2016-02-18T13:59:59".split()]
series = pd.Series(data=data, name='Date')

# apply the conversion function to series to create epoch series
epoch_series = series.apply(
    lambda x: convert_naive_dt_to_utc_epoch(x, timezone('US/Eastern')))

print(epoch_series)
```

**Results:**

```
0    1.476813e+09
1    1.455822e+09
Name: Date, dtype: float64
```